# Is there a MAX character limit on SNOWFLAKE

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

When copying data from Azure Data Factory to SnowFlake I get the following error from SnowFlake

```
Status Info
Status
Failed
Error count/Error limit
3/1
First error
User character length limit (400) exceeded by string '<div class="ExternalClassFEF297CEF4014BF7AC93A5068BA8801E"><div style="font-family&#58;Calibri, Arial'
Line:Position
2:0
Column name
"COMMENTARY"["COMMENTARY"
```

Is there way of determining the number of characters that is exceeding limit? Does SnowFlake have a way of just overriding the limit? Can you provide any suggestions on overcoming this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> User character length limit (400) exceeded by string '<div
> style="font-family:Calibri, Arial'

This means that the code submission contains a string that is longer than the maximum allowed character length of 400. The error occurs at line 2, position 0, within the "COMMENTARY" column.

To resolve this error, you need to either shorten the string or split it into multiple strings that are each less than 400 characters long.

Comment: An additional option is to change the limit of the affected column, which seems to be defined as varchar(400). Snowflake supports strings up to 16,777,216 characters, and simply removing the width will define the column as varchar max.